# Comunicar Checkbox com Python

Tags: javascript, html, python

Tenho um botão do tipo "checkbox" com um evento JS, os eventos JS estão funcionado normalmente, porem eu gostaria que meu código JS executasse um arquivo .py quando o checkbox estiver marcado. Como posso fazer isso?

esse é o codigo html

```
<div class="switch__container" >
    <input id="switch-shadow" class="switch switch--shadow" type="checkbox"name="field[]" value="1">
    <label for="switch-shadow"></label>
    <script src="js/teste.js"></script>
  </div>
```

esse é o codigo JS:

```
var checkbox = $("#switch-shadow[type='checkbox']");

checkbox.change(function(event) {
    var checkbox = event.target;

    if (checkbox.checked) {
        setTimeout(function(){

            alert("Luz do quarto Acessa") 

        }, 1000);    
    } 

    else {
        setTimeout(function(){ 

            alert("Luz do quarto Desligado")

        }, 1000);  
    }

});
```

Tem mais, o meu back-end é em python. Esse é o código:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import cgi, cgitb

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(18,GPIO.OUT)
print "LED on"
GPIO.output(18,GPIO.HIGH)
time.sleep(5)
print "LED off"
GPIO.output(18,GPIO.LOW)
```

Comment: Você tem um backend? Em qual linguagem?

Comment: python, esse é o codigo python:       

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(18,GPIO.OUT)
print "LED on"
GPIO.output(18,GPIO.HIGH)
time.sleep(5)
print "LED off"
GPIO.output(18,GPIO.LOW)

Comment: Não seria o caso de fazer um ajax quando ele selecionasse o checkbox?

Comment: sim, exatamente mas nao estou conseguindo estrutula-lo no meu JS

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver, basta utilizar o [`fetch`](https://braziljs.org/blog/fetch-api-e-o-javascript/) para resolver seu problema da seguinte forma:

```
checkbox.change(function(event) {
    const checkbox = event.target;
    fetch(`http://www.example.com/?status=${checkbox.checked}`)
    .then(function(response) {
        alert(response.data);
    });

}
```

Daí o seu backend ficaria encarregado de alterar o estado da luz, baseado no que foi enviado pra ele através do `GET` e dar o retorno de se foi acendida ou apagada e se houve ou não algum erro.

Comment: ok, vou testar, e te dou um retorno